# java mail connection com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

my server is localhost
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 456; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Instead of localhost set the server to the intranet ip that has access to Internet, most likely assigned by a router throught dhcp.

Comment: If your server is localhost, why did you configure JavaMail to connect to smtp.gmail.com?